# Launching boilerplate MEAN.io app to Nodejitsu: error

Tags: nodejitsu

Here is my gist: https://gist.github.com/AustinG08/9065353
Similar error message: https://github.com/nodejitsu/jitsu/issues/493

I clone the mean.io boilerplate. I don't see anything wrong with the package.json file. I have tried implementing what was mentioned in that similar error message but I guess I am too new. This is my first stackoverflow post. Please help.

*edit for more detail:
I do a git clone of github.com/linnovate/mean - the mean.io stack. I can run it locally just fine. But I want to deploy it to my nodejitsu account. I run 'jitsu deploy' in the command line and I get what is in the gist I linked. In the scripts section of package.json I try changing "start": "node node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt", to "start": "node server.js", based on that similar error message I found but to no avail, same thing happens.

Comment: I would suggest you describe what you have tried and describing the error in more detailed.

Comment: sorry, I do a git clone of https://github.com/linnovate/mean - the mean.io stack. I can run it locally just fine. But I want to deploy it to my nodejitsu account. I run 'jitsu deploy' in the command line and I get what is in the gist I linked. In the scripts section of package.json I try changing "start": "node node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt", to "start": "node server.js", based on that similar error message I found but to no avail, same thing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it thanks to your advice, but since you never posted your `package.json` file I'm entering it here fur further users which may stumble across this post with the same problem:

```
{
"name": "mean",
"description": "MEAN - A fullStack javascript framework powered by  MongoDB, ExpressJS, AngularJS, NodeJS.",
"version": "0.1.2-2",
"private": false,
"repository": {
  "type": "git",
  "url": "https://github.com/linnovate/mean.git"
},
"engines": {
  "node": "0.10.x",
  "npm": "1.3.x"
},
"scripts": {
  "start": "node server.js",
  "test": "node node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt test",
  "postinstall": "node node_modules/bower/bin/bower install"
},
"dependencies": {
  "express": "~3.4.7",
  "bower": "~1.2.8",
  "grunt-cli": "~0.1.11",
  "connect-mongo": "~0.4.0",
  "connect-flash": "~0.1.1",
  "consolidate": "~0.10.0",
  "swig": "~1.3.2",
  "mongoose": "~3.8.3",
  "passport": "~0.1.18",
  "passport-local": "~0.1.6",
  "passport-facebook": "~1.0.2",
  "passport-twitter": "~1.0.2",
  "passport-github": "~0.1.5",
  "passport-google-oauth": "~0.1.5",
  "passport-linkedin": "~0.1.3",
  "lodash": "~2.4.1",
  "forever": "~0.10.11",
  "view-helpers": "~0.1.4",
  "mean-logger": "0.0.1"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "grunt-env": "~0.4.1",
  "grunt-cli": "~0.1.11",
  "grunt-contrib-watch": "latest",
  "grunt-contrib-jshint": "latest",
  "grunt-karma": "~0.6.2",
  "grunt-nodemon": "0.2.0",
  "grunt-concurrent": "latest",
  "grunt-mocha-test": "latest",
  "karma": "~0.10.4",
  "karma-coffee-preprocessor": "~0.1.0",
  "karma-coverage": "~0.1.0",
  "karma-script-launcher": "~0.1.0",
  "karma-chrome-launcher": "~0.1.0",
  "karma-firefox-launcher": "~0.1.0",
  "karma-html2js-preprocessor": "~0.1.0",
  "karma-jasmine": "~0.1.3",
  "karma-requirejs": "~0.2.0",
  "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "~0.1.0",
  "forever": "~0.10.11",
  "supertest": "0.8.2",
  "should": "2.1.1"
},
"subdomain": "hitman666-mean2"
}
```

After making this change I deployed my application once more, and everything went without an error, but when I browsed it on Nodejitsu I got an error: `502 Reached max retries limit`.

I realized that I don’t have a correct MongoDB connection string, and in order to change this I had to edit the file `production.js` which is in the `config/env/`  folder. I copied the MongoDB connection string from Nodejitsu’s admin dashboard (I wrote about how to set this on my blog post [Getting started with Nodejitsu on Windows by deploying a MEN framework](http://nikola-breznjak.com/blog/nodejs/getting-started-with-nodejitsu-on-windows-by-deploying-a-men-framework/)).

After this change I deployed my app again, and now everything was working, yay!

P.S. If someone is interested, the whole blog post on how I did this is here: [Deploying MEAN.io to Nodejitsu from Windows machine](http://nikola-breznjak.com/blog/nodejs/deploying-mean-io-to-nodejitsu-from-windows-machine/)

Comment: Hey, sorry. Thanks for posting this. +1

Answer (score 1):

OK! Well, I got it deployed on nodejitsu thanks to help from the #node.js channel. The gist of it was I had to move all grunt, karma, and forever dependencies to my devDependencies in the package.json file and change my start to "node server".

Comment: could you maybe try to explain this a little bit better how did you make it in the end?